# How do I use silversearcher-ag with Emacs without a package

Tags: ag

I've read `Grep Searching` from the manual. The basic that I've found out are that I can use `grep` command in Emacs. I was wondering if I could use `silversearcher-ag` as an alternative to `grep` in `M-x grep`

I tried to just remove `grep --color -nH --null -e` and use plain `ag` command and it does actually work, i.e. it fills up the `*grep*` buffer. But it's not formatted and thus Emacs can't use that buffer to jump around the matches.

I know about some packages, but I really want to know how I can change the `ag` command so that the output is compatible for Emacs. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize settings like this:

```
  (setq grep-command "ag --vimgrep "
        grep-use-null-device nil)
```

I've tested it with `emacs -Q --eval "(setq grep-command \"ag --vimgrep \" grep-use-null-device nil)"`

Comment: Got error: `(void-variable \"ag)`. It works okay without the backslashes though. Maybe you used escaping because you were invoking the command from bash.

Comment: My bad, you're right, string escaping is only needed in bash. Have corrected my answer, thanks.

Comment: Another query of mine is, what is the differences between normal ag and --vimgrep output that Emacs recognizes one and doesn't another?

Comment: Because `grep-mode` only recognises lines like `A:B:C` , where A is file path, B is line number, and C is the matched line, which `ag` doesn't default to.

Answer (score 0):

`M-x grep RET ag --nogroup PATTERN RET` almost works, if you search against only one file, because `ag --nogroup PATTERN FILE` doesn't print the filename in such case, e.g.,

```
~/.emacs.d $ ag --nogroup user-init-file init.el
1404:         (not (eq (current-buffer) (get-file-buffer user-init-file)))
```

you can append a empty file such as `/dev/null` to force ag to print the file name:

```
ag --nogroup PATTERN FILE /dev/null
```

or set `grep-use-null-device` to `t` so Emacs will add the empty file for you:

```
(setq grep-use-null-device t)
```

Besides, colors doesn't work and you can jump the correct line but not the right column. Now I know more or less why ag.el is created, even I haven't tried it.